# App crashes while using error handler middleware using Expresss JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am working on a NodeJS app using Express framework.

I have created this error handler middleware which is called at the very end of the app.js file

```
//An error handling middleware
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    err.statusCode = err.statusCode || 500;
    err.status = err.status || 'error';

    res.status(err.statusCode).json({
        status: err.status,
        message: err.message,
    });
});
```

And in my routes or controllers js files, whenever I catch an error, I am redirecting them to this middleware using this code

```
if (err) {
   next(err);
}
```

but this crashes the app. any idea?

Comment: Can you provide a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: @aslamdoctor Can you elaborate more on how are you chaining middlewares. Also please add some stack trace of your error.

Comment: You can find the code here commented as 
//An error handling middleware


https://github.com/aslamdoctor/nodejs-rest-api-boilerplate-mysql/blob/master/app.js

Comment: Although I changed my code from just using 
``next(err)``

to
``return next(err);``

As for some reason the middleware was returning back to the controller code where it was called from.